# Maintain user login state in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have been working with Firebase and made users with this code;

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value,password.value).catch(function(error) {
});
```

and I checked my Firebase console and they were getting registered.

So then i tried to make a login for them using this code

```
l_submit.addEventListener('click',function(){
            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(l_email.value, l_password.value).catch(function(error){
              var errorCode = error.code;
              var errorMessage = error.message;
              console.log(error.message);
              flag=1;
            });
            if(flag==0)
            {
                //window.location.assign("/admin.html");
                console.log("login successful");
            }
        });
```

checked the state with this code

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user) {
              // User is signed in.
               console.log("user");
            } else {
              console.log("no user");
            }
```

it shows user printed in console.

But when I navigate to other pages, the `auth().currentUser` code says no user.

So how do I maintain the login state across other pages?

Comment: Does the same happen when you refresh the page?

Comment: ok, idk what happened but yesterday after printing the login successful it was printing user not it is printing login successful and not printing user ....also in the firebase console in auth tab it shows signed in date as today

Comment: ok now user is getting printed after I login with the right credentials, but if i refresh the page it says no user

Comment: Try to save the details in `localStorage` and use it further!

Comment: User authentication state is automatically persisted to local storage across pages. Can you [attach on `onAuthStateChanged()` listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) to see if it is picked up there. If that does work, it is likely that the client is still loading the data when you check `firebase.auth().currentUser`.

Answer (score 0):

I was using all of this on the front end, I changed my server to node.js now everything is working fine, every function is returning the values correctly.

Maybe it was a very silly mistake to use everything on the webpages itself as client was able to see everything like token link and all.

Thanks for your help guys